# Javascript random array

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

```
var title = 'a', 'b';
var length = 326, '424';
```

how do I get a random pick from the options and make sure that if it picks 'a' then it needs to pick '326' with it and then how do you assign them a number?

For instances 
if it picks a it automatically needs to get 326 with it and then I need to give something like

```
 var title1 = (picked number) 
    var length = (picked with number)
```

and then the other it didn't pick I need it to make it

```
var title2 = (title it didn't pick)
var title2 = (didnt get picked length)
```

Comment: Use a better suited data structure in the first place: An array of arrays or objects, where the latter holds _both_ values – then you only have to pick a random value from that array, and you have access to both values that belong together at once.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `var length = 326, '424';`? because that doesn't make much sense in Javascript.  Do you mean `var length = [326, 424]` where you can select either one from the array?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own object:

```
data=new Array();
data[0]=new Data('a',326);
data[1]=new Data('b',424);

function Data(title,length) {
    this.title=title;
    this.length=length;
    return this;
}

console.log(data);
```

Now you only need to choose a random element from the `data` array. To access the values use:

```
data[0].title
data[0].length
```

for example.

Comment: how do I choose a random element from the data array?  and you said to access it by doing data[0] but what if it is data[1]? do I just do data[1